# How to fix or handle the File Reaper thread memory leak issue in Java Struts 1.3 application deployed in Apache Tomcat 7.0.41?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

I have deployed a Struts 1.3 web application in Apache Tomcat 7.0.41. The tomcat server seems to often hang & fails to process any request showing the page not found error on the browser resembling a stopped tomcat server, but actually in the Windows Services the tomcat service is still shown as **Started**. The server works fine after a restart.

The following error was logged in **Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\logs\tomcat7-stderr.2013-07-05.log**

```
Jul 5, 2013 11:57:48 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
    SEVERE: The web application [/pms] appears to have started a thread named [File Reaper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
    Jul 5, 2013 11:57:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
    INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8085"]
    Jul 5, 2013 11:57:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
    INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"]
     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.krwssa.log.SystemLogManager.getLogger(SystemLogManager.java:39)
        at com.krwssa.db.DatabaseConnection.<clinit>(DatabaseConnection.java:14)
        at com.krwssa.action.LoginAction.login(LoginAction.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:274)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:194)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Exception in thread "http-bio-8085-exec-127" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    Exception in thread "http-bio-8085-exec-133" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(InternalInputBuffer.java:99)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:931)
    Exception in thread "http-bio-8085-exec-103" Exception in thread "http-bio-8085-Acceptor-0"     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    Exception in thread "http-bio-8085-AsyncTimeout"    at java.net.Socket.setSoLinger(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProperties.setProperties(SocketProperties.java:194)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.setSocketOptions(JIoEndpoint.java:485)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:228)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    2013-07-05 06:57:58 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
```

The web application does contain some forms that have Struts 1.3 FormFile elements that are used to upload files to the server. The application worked fine in Tomcat's development mode that is configured in MyEclipse IDE. It seems that File Reaper thread is the culprit or is it? How to fix or handle this issue?

Regards,
Shiva

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the database settings to run with the Tomcat server. There's unknown from your post configuration but I guess that you just didn't include database drivers with your application, or the database drivers aren't installed at Tomcat sever.

Comment: Hi Roman C, Thanks for replying. I had put the database JARs in the Tomcat's lib folder. One thing to note is that I had put 32 bit JDBC drivers for Oracle. Does it matter if we put 32-jar JDBC drivers for Oracle instead of 64-bit JDBC drivers? The server machine is 64 bit machine & Oracle version installed is 11g 64 bit.

Comment: It matters to Tomcat if it's running 32bit then ok.

Comment: Let me see if the tomcat server hangs again, I have replaced the 32-bit JDBC drivers by 64 bit drivers. Is there anything else I have to change? As the relationship between File Reaper THREAD memory leak error and JDBC JAR drivers seems far-off.

Comment: Hello Everybody, The problem continues to persist. Any suggestions that could fix this problem?

Comment: @Shiva I'd like to help you, but it seems you don't like to follow me. If you run Tomcat on JDK 32bit the you need 32bit drivers, or use better thin driver, otherwise use 64bit.

Comment: Hi Roman C, The Java JDK installed is 32 bit, tomcat service is installed from the exe file (so, it is 32/64 bit) and Oracle is 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit. Before posting the issue here, I had put the oracle JDBC 32 bit drivers in Tomcat lib folder. After that I changed it to 64 bit JDBC oracle drivers. Still it runs out of memory and eventually hangs. So, should I revert back to 32-bit JDBC Drivers for Oracle?

Comment: @Shiva You can't use 32bit drivers with the Oracle 64bit, unless you install the Oracle Client 32bit but it seems weird on the same comp. Do you running it on the same comp? If you wanna force the problem platform resolution then remove 32 bit versions of Java and Tomcat and use 64bit equivalent. Oracle with the db installs another JRE that would be 64bit if your Oracle is 64bit. Don't use this JRE, install 64bit Java JDK and put it on JAVA_HOME then 64 bit Tomcat, then you could use 64bit drivers.